# How to format a DockerFile to look at a sub-directory where the app is

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

My DockerFile is looking for `.go` files in the wrong directory, it needs to be looking at the sub-directory called `app`

Here is my folder set up, parent folder is `my-app`

```
my-app/
├─ app/
│  ├─ api
│  ├─ go.mod
│  ├─ go.sum
│  ├─ main.go
DockerFile
```

DockerFile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/docker-gs-ping" ]
```

As for now the DockerFile is looking for the `go` files in the directory where DockerFile is, not in the `app` sub-directory. Where can I fix that?

Comment: `COPY app/*.go` ?

Comment: ^ this - or if it's too cumbersome to change all of a `Dockerfile`'s reference, specify a different directory context during your build. So instead of `docker build .`  instead use `docker build ./app`

Comment: This is exactly what the context is for,  so unless you need to copy files that aren't in app/ , it's a perfect fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand it should be like this, basically copy everything to the app, run the download and build commands.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY app/ .
RUN go mod download    
RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "/docker-gs-ping" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a possible solution building a lightweight docker image

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM golang:1.16-alpine as builder
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64
WORKDIR /app
COPY app/* ./
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /docker-gs-pings *.go
EXPOSE 8080

FROM scratch
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=builder /docker-gs-pings /
CMD [ "/docker-gs-pings" ]
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. What makes this lightweight? Would this be "better" than the example above?

Comment: @woof "scratch" docker image is an explicitly empty image (no OS filesystem). Basically it builds an image with just your program binary inside. One disadvantage is that you can not init a login shell inside the container (no OS filesystem) when using "scratch", but if you need it, then you can use another base image instead of "scratch" such as "debian". Search on internet for "building multistage docker images".